# autoproj snapshot with git detached HEAD

Tags: rock

I need to search in the git history of a couple of packages to 
get back to a working state for a demo. I am searching by checking out 
commits manually until I found the commits of all effected packages that 
work together.

By checking out commits manually, I will get into the detached HEAD state:

$ git checkout 995e018
-> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. [...]

To save the current state of all packages, a snapshot is created:

$ autoproj snapshot demo_working

Now the demo_working/overrides.yml will pin the commit where the HEAD is 
pointing to (e.g. 5e2e3a259) instead of the commit that I chose manually 
for the package (995e018).

Is this the desired behaviour? In my opinion a snapshot should store the 
current state of all my git repositories meaning that I can also select 
commits manually.

Comment: For future reference, you can binary search the last commit where a condition was satisfied (e.g. before a bug was introduced, or while everything still worked) using [git bisect](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with git HEADs is just a bad idea, so yes, this behaviour is expected.

What you want to do is reset your current branch to the desired commit, i.e.

```
git reset --hard 995e018
```

which will be picked up by autoproj